# Error 500 del jQuery al ejecutar un GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un pequeño script que llama a un archivo PHP pero no me funciona, me lanza error 500 por la consola de Chrome...

La idea es que al seleccionar un elemento en un textlist pues ejecute el código PHP y lo imprima dentro de un table que tiene su respectivo ID... el script es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#codigo").change(function(){
      $.get("admin/actions/checkbox_mantenimiento.php","codigo="+$("#codigo").val(), function(data){
        $("#tipos_mant").html(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Y el PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if(isset($_GET['codigo']))
{
    $codigoequipo=$_GET['codigo'];

    if($codigoequipo=="") {
        echo "Ningún equipo seleccionado.";
    }

    else {  
        $consulequipo = "SELECT * FROM maquinarias WHERE serialequipo = '$codigoequipo'";
        $consultipos = "SELECT * FROM mantenimiento WHERE codigo = '$codigoequipo'";

        $equipo = $bd->consulta($consulequipo);
        $tipos = $bd->consulta($consultipos);

        if ($rowtipos = $tipos->fetch_assoc() && $rowequipo = $equipo->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cantidadcb = $rowtipos['nro_tipos'];

            $checkboxes = while ($trigger < $cantidadcb) {
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td width=\"50%\">
                            <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rowtipos['tipo'.$trigger]."required name=\"op_".$trigger."\">
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                $trigger++;
            }

            echo "
                <form role=\"form\" action=\"?admin=mperiod&crearperiod=crearperiod\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr colspan=\"2\" width=\"50%\">
                            <td>
                                <input type=\"text\" class+\"form-control\" value=\"".$rowequipo['serialequipo']."\" name=\"codigo\" readonly required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tipos de Mantenimiento Asociados</th>
                        <tr>
                    <thead>

                    <tbody>
                        ".$checkboxes."
                    <tbody>
                        <tr> 
                            <td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\"><center>
                                <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\" name=\"lugarguardar\" value=\"Guardar\">Registrar</button></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </form>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Si necesitan algo adicional estoy presto a facilitar lo necesario. Gracias de antemano por todo.

Answer (score 1):

Que raro que escapes todas las comillas dobles. Para no estar haciéndolo te recomiendo que uses comillas sencillas en el echo, te quedaría algo así

```
echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" 
      value="'.$rowequipo['serialequipo'].'" name="codigo" readonly required>';
```

Ahora esto está medio raro, no veo en tu código declarada la variable `$trigger`

```
$checkboxes = while ($trigger < $cantidadcb) {
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td width=\"50%\">
                            <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rowtipos['tipo'.$trigger]."required name=\"op_".$trigger."\">
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                $trigger++;
            }
```

Nunca lo he hecho así, pero considero que puede ser tu salvación esto

```
$trigger = 0;
$checkboxes = '';
while ($trigger < $cantidadcb) {
                $checkboxes.= "
                    <tr>
                        <td width=\"50%\">
                            <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rowtipos['tipo'.$trigger]."required name=\"op_".$trigger."\">
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                $trigger++;
            }
```

Quizá así salgas del error que es lo más probable. De no ser así, entonces activa la traza de errores al inicio de tu script de la siguiente forma

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("config.php");

if(isset($_GET['codigo']))
{
   ...
}
```

En el preview de la consola de Chrome te lanzará nuevamente el error 500 pero ya con el detalle de dónde te equivocaste

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Hice lo que me indicaste, en efecto no había creado las variables...aunque sigue dando error 500. Ahora bien, en la consola de Chrome el error lo indica en el archivo jquery-1.10.2.min.js en la línea 6. Quizá si actualizo el archivo a una versión mas reciente...se solucionará el inconveniente?

Comment: Eso depende, si no afecta tu demás código, puedes hacer el upgrade a la 3.X e intentar hacerlo con AJAX, ahora el error 500 es un error propio del servidor, donde hay algo mal en el script y no se puede ejecutar.